# Is protractor, in any way dependent on AngularJS version?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have just started to use protractor. I wanted to know it's limitation and specifically if it is dependent on version of AngularJS

Answer (score 2):

I don't complete agree with @Zanon here. `Protractor` actually relies on some Angular-specific things like `getTestability` test helper that helps to let Protractor know that Angular is stable, ready and there are no outstanding requests left ([source](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/63e330d24f75162a8a603bdde6d0a68a8af555ca/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L65)). This is actually what makes `Protractor` somewhat special and is recommended to use for testing Angular apps - the test flow becomes more natural, there is usually no need for extra waits - Protractor just works in sync with Angular application under test.

To answer your specific question:

- for testing Angular 1.x apps - you can use any Protractor version
- for testing Angular 2.x apps - Protractor >= [2.5.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#250)

Answer (score 1):

**No**, Protractor is not dependent on any specific Angular 1.x version.

**However**, since Angular 2.x added big new and breaking changes, you need Protractor version 2.5 (or later) to use it (you can confirm [this here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#250)).

Protractor is a Node.js program that uses browser drives to execute tests as a real user would. It was designed thinking on Angular workflows, but it doesn't use Angular code, so its dependency is by design choices and not on specific code versions.